# In Keras, how can I arbitrarily resize a 1D Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In order to make a keras concatenation operation between a single channel image and a 1-dimensional tensor possible, I need to reshape the length of my 1-dimensional tensor to match two of the image dimensions and **pad all of the extra neurons with zeroes**. How can I do this?

Example code to show an equivalent problem:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Reshape, concatenate

inputs = Input(shape = (784,))

dense_layer = Dense(10)(inputs)

reshaped_layer = Reshape((28, 28, 1))(inputs)

convolved_layer = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(reshaped_layer)

concatenated_layer = concatenate([convolved_layer, dense_layer])
```

*ValueError: Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 26, 26, 10), (None, 10)]*

Of course, I cannot use Reshape on the 1-dimensional tensor to do this since it doesn't have the right number of neurons, and I don't want to flatten and reshape the convolved layer, since that would involve losing useful spatial information.
Is there some way that I could use a numpy array to make a new keras layer of the right shape, containing the `dense_layer` data and padding?

Comment: So, you have a Tensor A with shape (26, 26, 10) and a Tensor B with shape (10,), and you want to concatenate them together? How do you want to do so? So that you have a Tensor C with shape (27, 27, 10), where C[-1, -1, :] = B?

Comment: Well, since the convolved_layer is a stack of 10 26x26 filtered images, I could take the dense_layer and form it into a 26x26 pixel image, where the first 10 pixels are the values of the dense layer (and the rest are zeroes), and lay it atop the 10 filtered images. In which case the concatenated_layer would end up with dimensions (26, 26, 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the Keras ZeroPadding1D layer is what I needed. (The clue was in the name).

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Reshape, concatenate, ZeroPadding1D

inputs = Input(shape = (784,))

dense_layer = Dense(10)(inputs)

dense_layer_with_added_axis = Reshape((10, 1))(dense_layer)

dense_zero_padded = ZeroPadding1D(333)(dense_layer_with_added_axis)

dense_reshaped = Reshape((26, 26, 1))(dense_zero_padded)

reshaped_layer = Reshape((28, 28, 1))(inputs)

convolved_layer = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(reshaped_layer)

concatenated_layer = concatenate([convolved_layer, dense_reshaped])

print(concatenated_layer._keras_shape)
```

Outputs: *(None, 26, 26, 11)*

The argument to the ZeroPadding1D layer is the number of zeroes to add **on either side of the input tensor**. So in this case, layer `dense_zero_padded` is a 1D array consisting of 333 zeroes, 10 values from `dense_layer` and another 333 zeroes. This is then reshaped into a (26, 26, 1) tensor, which can stack nicely atop the filtered images of `convolved_layer`.